# py3exiv2 installed but module not found?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
jrc$ ~/bin/photos/NVlistTagsFromPhoto.py  014.jpg 
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/jrc/bin/photos/NVlistTagsFromPhoto.py", line 29, in <module>
import py3exiv2
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'py3exiv2'
jrc$ pip3 install py3exiv2
Requirement already satisfied: py3exiv2 in /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages (0.11.0)
jrc$ type python3
python3 is /usr/local/bin/python3
```

I updated and upgraded all the new hierarchies before.

I tried to list the EXIF tag

EDIT:
Solved, the name of the module to import is not py3exiv2 as the install seems to say, but pyexiv2.

Comment: What is the shebang line of your Python script? Is it the same python3 where you installed py3exiv2? Is your pip3 the same environment as your python3? How about doing `python3 -m pip install py3exiv2`?

Comment: Basically, the Python you use to run your app should be the same Python where you install your packages.